# How to test maximum connection Node JS websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm writing an Node JS socket App.
Case1: Base on this link

stackabuse.com/node-js-websocket-examples-with-socket-io/

I start the server on port 3000, go to browser, navigate to localhost:3000, i got index.html page and an connection to socket inside this file (you can find it in the link above).
This is my code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
console.log(current);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
//console.log('a user connected');

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
io.emit('chat message', msg);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
});
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Case 2: I include socket.io.js file inside index.html file, then access it from browser (but not with port 3000 anymore) with apache like an normal site).

[Code for Node server case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y34Wz.png)

Then the script will create an websocket to localhost:3000 like this:

[Client case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4YYN.png)

I only can test the maximum connect with case 1 (actually send alot GET request to get "index.html" page, not an real socket connection). I tested with thor, loadtest, benchmark, Artillery... and they're only work with case 1 :(

So, can I have any tool to test maximum connection in Websocket Node JS? I really need an usable tool to test  websocket (not just HTTP GET).

Thansk for reading this question, and sorry for my English, by the way :(

Comment: Please add your code here!

Comment: I added, sorry for my mistake. Can you take a look at my code?